# Why I can't store a timestamp in mysql / phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table created in phpMyAdmin and it contains two fields: start_time and text_modified. It looks like this

[image: http://i.imgur.com/fHcWyOh.png]

so the start_time might be null.
When I'm filling the data in phpmyadmin I can choose the date and time that should be represented as this timestamp:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/XvpjuPS.png]

After doing so I expect to store a timestamp value in this field instead of date time. But when I do a query `SELECT start_time from table` I see there this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Nwam2e1.png]

So I assumed that it is just the php my admin that shows me automatically all dates as a date time value instead of timestamps. But now when I do a query: `SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(start_time) FROM table` I'm getting those results:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/gOZdoU3.png]

and instead I want normal dates here. What is going wrong here?

Comment: Try `CAST(start_time AS UNSIGNED INTEGER)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a timestamp you can insert datetime values, that are internally stored as integers (the seconds since 1970-01-01 as you probably know). When you select them, they are displayed as date and time.

So far so good.

When you have values like `0000-00-00 00:00:00` you probably inserted `NULL` values or invalid dates or dates out of range for the integer value. Using `FROM_UNIXTIME()` doesn't make sense here, since this function calculates a date and time value from an integer value. This integer value of the timestamp column is like I said only used internally. Therefore you get `NULL` values for valid dates and `1970-01-01` for invalid dates since those were presumably treated as `0` and `0` seconds since `1970-01-01 00:00:00` is, surprise, `1970-01-01 00:00:00`.

Comment: Thanks. So what's the safest way of storing timestamps in database? Should I just change it to int? and if so, what are the benefits of using timestamp field instead?

Comment: What do you mean with "safest way". What problems are you encountering that make anything unsafe? The benefit of timestamp over datetime is for example the fewer data storage requirement (4 bytes vs 8 bytes). About all the differences between the different datatypes I recommend to have a look in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-types.html).